# Cloud Functions Writing custom fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm starting to write cloud functions that allow for client side transactions. In the below code my goal is to create a "post2" collection that is an abbreviated copy of my "post" collection. This is working well, except that the document name author is not pulling in the actual author name when it writes to Firebase. How can I pull in the actual author's name as opposed to the word "${author}" as the document name?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();


exports.createPostSecondary = functions.firestore
    .document(`post/{documentID}`)
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const article: string = snap.data().article;
        const article_title: string = snap.data().article_title;
        const author: string = snap.data().author;
        const comment: string = snap.data().comment;

        await admin.firestore().doc('posts2/${author}').set({
            article: article,
            article_title: article_title,
            author: author,

        })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, if you're trying to build a string by inserting placeholders for variables, use backticks (instead of single quotes) to tell JS you want it to do string interpolation:

```
`posts2/${author}`
```

Comment: Thanks! JS novice here, appreciate the callout.